# Transaction taking too long on Ropsten testnet

Tags: transactions, testrpc, ropsten

I checked the syncing status, it returns false. I submitted transaction with a very high gas value but it takes long time to get completed. This is my local ropsten node:

```
INFO [08-06|13:16:45.473] Imported new chain segment               blocks=20 txs=485 mgas=36.216 elapsed=8.801s    mgasps=4.115  number=3781888 hash=c6044b…699f1f cache=14.53mB
INFO [08-06|13:16:54.141] Imported new chain segment               blocks=33 txs=513 mgas=48.793 elapsed=8.668s    mgasps=5.629  number=3781921 hash=eedfea…5493ef cache=14.97mB
INFO [08-06|13:16:55.307] Imported new chain segment               blocks=5  txs=85  mgas=11.554 elapsed=1.166s    mgasps=9.905  number=3781926 hash=90df4a…40f450 cache=15.09mB
INFO [08-06|13:18:17.611] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x84053eabcb71a8081832d17b10b5145fd292fcce9fb1fa9d5b3694812c9ade1f recipient=0x830954070CA0051Eb6941314158c0A65CF756296
INFO [08-06|13:19:52.805] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xfdccd022ef614bd73318272212fd765428882c6d988177a611286247edae9b2b recipient=0x830954070CA0051Eb6941314158c0A65CF756296
INFO [08-06|13:20:09.826] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x6011cdf5281e82e8a1143e32248061f364290cb7005d033c663cabc2dc2c962d recipient=0x830954070CA0051Eb6941314158c0A65CF756296






INFO [08-06|13:21:01.424] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xe7ce20f1d5e6668826aad9bcdf4b96290ac9058ec2f02161621da97101c65242 recipient=0x830954070CA0051Eb6941314158c0A65CF756296
INFO [08-06|13:21:18.071] Imported new chain segment               blocks=2  txs=32  mgas=1.270  elapsed=212.207ms mgasps=5.983  number=3781928 hash=27dcc9…fb721f cache=15.05mB
INFO [08-06|13:21:19.054] Imported new chain segment               blocks=3  txs=17  mgas=0.506  elapsed=125.386ms mgasps=4.032  number=3781931 hash=09bf3f…df3b02 cache=14.91mB
INFO [08-06|13:21:28.149] Imported new chain segment               blocks=8  txs=278 mgas=27.496 elapsed=8.187s    mgasps=3.358  number=3781939 hash=7879aa…e0f9c0 cache=15.22mB
INFO [08-06|13:21:31.078] Imported new chain segment               blocks=11 txs=267 mgas=20.008 elapsed=2.925s    mgasps=6.839  number=3781950 hash=abcd65…d2113f cache=15.36mB
```

I called contract method through web3.js to add struct(containing 2 string) to a list.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the max gas to a high value, correct.

However, your gasPrice is actually 0. You're lucky that it's a testnet, and they still get mined. Transactions with a gasPrice of 0 will take months to be mined on the mainnet, if at all.

You need a gasPrice in addition to the gas parameter. For ropsten, even 1 gwei is enough. For the mainnet, 1-5 gwei works, depending on how busy the network is.

Comment: Thanks. Are transactions executed in the same order they are submitted ? Or they can be picked up(pending) in any order ?